# How to save a system.drawing.graphics object to a PDF file using PDFsharp?

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, pdfsharp, system.drawing.graphics

I have searched for hours trying to find out how to do this without any success.

I did find the 'FromGraphics' command which reads a 'system.drawing.graphics' object into the XGraphics type, but am unsure how to add this to the PDF output.

Most examples I find show how to take images from an existing file and save them to a PDF, but how do I do this with a pre-made system.drawing.graphics object that has been made pragmatically?

A C# and/or VB.net example would be very much appreciated instead of a GIF.

E.g. how do I change an example like the following to use the system.drawing.graphics object?

```
string pdfpath = Server.MapPath("PDFs");
string imagepath = Server.MapPath("Images");
Document doc = new Document();
try
{
  PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdfpath + "/Images.pdf",   FileMode.Create));
  doc.Open();

  doc.Add(new Paragraph("GIF"));
  Image gif = Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/mikesdotnetting.gif");
  doc.Add(gif);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  //Log error;
}
finally
{
  doc.Close();
}
```

Comment: You have gotten good answers. Just to make sure you get this right: The Graphics obejct __does not contain ANY graphics__. It is just a tool to paint pixels on a) a surface b) a bitmap c) a printPage. Or  d) into a PDF, if you use the special Graphics object from your pdf lib..

Answer (score 2):

Short example:

```
Dim pdfDoc As New PdfDocument
Dim page As New PdfPage
pdfDoc.Pages.Add(page)
Dim xg = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page)
 'use the xg object to draw on the pdf page
pdfDoc.Save("path to file")
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting this.

If I have a pre-made system.drawing.graphics object stored to graphics and I move this it to an XGraphics gfx object:

Eg. XGraphics gfx = FromGraphics(graphics, size)

How do I add the gfx object to the PDF file page?
Do I use the image type, and if so how?

Comment: Call the methods on the `xg` object. i.e. `xg.DrawString(...)`

Comment: I use the `XGraphics.FromPdfPage` myself. It draws right to the page.

Comment: The `FromGraphics(graphics, size)` will draw on the control that has the Graphics(like a picturebox) - see the [docs](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) so this method does not draw to the pdf page

Comment: the `Graphics` object does not store anything, the `GraphicsPath` does.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the main question "How to save a system.drawing.graphics object to a PDF file using PDFsharp?"
You can't do that. You can use the XGraphics class to draw on PDF pages, on the screen, on a printer. You can create an XGraphics object for a PDF page or from a Graphics object. But anything that was drawn on the Graphics object with other than XGraphics routines will not appear in the PDF.

The other question: "How do I change an example like the following to use the system.drawing.graphics object?"
You need an XGraphics object to draw on PDF. User OneFineDay showed how to get one. Then you use `xg.DrawImage(...)` to draw images on a PDF page. You do not need a Graphics object unless you also want to draw on other media than PDF pages.